# Value from Visualforce UI not reflected in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I have an `<apex:inputField>` in my visualforce page that controls a custom wrapper object which the user can update and then saves using `<apex:commandButton>` to my controller. The problem is the field that is supposed to be updated by the user is not reflected in the controller.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:form id="salesRepForm">
<apex:pageBlock id="srTargetBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <!-- THE BUTTON USED -->
        <apex:commandButton action="{!quickSaveSRTargets}"
            value="{!$Label.EUR_CRM_Quick_Save }" reRender="salesRepForm" status="loadingStatus" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!SalesRepAndSalesAgencyTargetWraps}" var="srTargetWrap" id="srTargetTable">
            <apex:column >
                <table width="100%">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!srTargetWrap.srTargets}" var="srTarget">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%"><apex:outputField value="{!srTarget.EUR_CRM_Target_Owner__c}" /></td>
                            <td width="40%">
                                <!-- THE INPUT FIELD IN QUESTION -->
                                <apex:inputField styleClass="srTarget"
                                    value="{!srTarget.EUR_CRM_Qty_Sell_in_Amount_Bottle__c}"
                                    style="text-align:right" rendered="{!isDraft}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </table>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Wrapper Class:

```
public class TargetWrap{

    public EUR_CRM_ObjPromo_Target__c target{get;set;}
    public List<EUR_CRM_ObjPromo_Target__c> srTargets{get;set;}

    public TargetWrap(List<EUR_CRM_ObjPromo_Target__c> srTargets, EUR_CRM_ObjPromo_Target__c target){
        this.target= target;
        this.srTargets = srTargets;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public List<TargetWrap> salesRepTargetWrap {get; set;}

public List<TargetWrap> getSalesRepAndSalesAgencyTargetWraps(){ 
    salesRepTargetWrap = new List<TargetWrap>();
    // Retrieves relevant data and construct a list of Wrapper Class
    salesRepTargetWrap.addAll(retrieveRelevantData());    

    return salesRepTargetWrap;
}
```

Save method in the controller:

```
public PageReference quickSaveSRTargets() {
    // TODO: SalesRepTargetWrap are not updated from the VF Page
    if(salesRepTargetWrap != null && salesRepTargetWrap.size() > 0) {

        // BUG BELOW
        System.debug(salesRepTargetWrap); // EUR_CRM_Qty_Sell_in_Amount_Bottle__c is not updated for all elements in the Wrapper list

        // ...
        // Additional logic to upsert records

        upsert newSRTargets;
    }

    return refresh();
}
```

Furthermore, the UI looks like the image below. Any value put in the input field (and pressing Quick Save button) will not be reflected in the controller (as shown by `System.debug` statements in the controller).
[image: UI]

Any suggestions or guidance will be accepted! Thanks.

Comment: You have used `rendered` attribute for the inputField, so some records won't be available to edit

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case, since those inputField are actually rendered on the page. I have edited the post to include the UI (see the attached picture). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved this problem by integrating `getSalesRepAndSalesAgencyTargetWraps()` with the wrapper's getter function in the controller.

I think the problem happens because the list returned from the actual `get;` getter (called from the controller when saving) and `getSalesRepAndSalesAgencyTargetWraps()` (called from the UI when rendering) might not be the same instance, hence why modifying them in the UI doesn't reflect to the controller.

Here's the modified controller:

```
public List<TargetWrap> salesRepTargetWrap {
    get {
        salesRepTargetWrap = new List<TargetWrap>();
        // Retrieves relevant data and construct a list of Wrapper Class
        salesRepTargetWrap.addAll(retrieveRelevantData());    

        return salesRepTargetWrap;          
    }

    set;
}
```